# Entity from database directly linked to viewModel - bad practice?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm using Entity Framework together with MVVM.
My layers look like this:

- View
- ViewModel: Provides data and commands for the view.
- Service: Provides access to the DAL. Contains business logic.
- DAL: Provides access to the database. I'm using the repository pattern together with a UnitOfWork.

The properties in my ViewModels are more or less directly bound to an entity from my database. Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyEntity _myEntity;

    private MyService _myService;

    // A property which is bound to my view (bidirectionally)
    public string TextToDisplay
    {
        get { return _myEntity.SomeText; }
        set
        {
            if (_myEntity.SomeText != value)
            {
                _myEntity.SomeText = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextToDisplay");
            }
        }
    }

    // Method called by a command when the "Save"-button is pressed
    private void Save()
    {
        _myService.Save(_myEntity);
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private MyRepository _myRepository;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public void Save(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        _myRepository.Insert(myEntity);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

So when `Save` is called, the database-generated attributes/properties (like `ID`) are updated/generated automatically.

Does this lead to side-effects? Is it a bad practice?

How do you handle it? Do you "detach" or copy objects when passing them from your database to your viewmodel? Or should the object passed to the viewmodel even be another type? How can I handle this perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this lead to side-effects? Is it a bad practice?

No. You are not violating any principles of the MVVM pattern and this is as close to ideal as possible as you have fully separated concerns and more importantly abstracted away from the DAL technology you are using with an abstract Model/Service implementation layer which not everyone does (some devs would inject the `DbContext`-derived class as the Model object and call `Save()` directly).

> How do you handle it? Do you "detach" or copy objects when passing them from your database to your viewmodel? Or should the object passed to the viewmodel even be another type? How can I handle this perfectly?

You could go further by making sure you depend on abstractions instead of concretions by either passing `IMyEntity` objects around or making sure that `MyEntity` is a base class and a more specialised EF DAL class is handled and passed around the DAL layer, but I've previously found this to be overkill for these types of applications.

I prefer not to use copy objects due to the code bloat. I have used the child/base-class entity hierarchy before very effectively, however, it is more work and there is no real reason to do so unless you know for a fact that you need to cater for multiple child-types from the start.